# swipe to delete searcharray leaves the delete toggle on the left

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

im new to obj-c and coding in general but im catching on really quick. i've come here looking for some guidance. im not sure how to word my problem so i made some [visuals](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBJg9.jpg)

when i delete a cell from the tableVC, it deletes without issues.

when i delete a cell while in a search, it deletes without issues.

after i delete a cell while in search and end my search by hitting cancel, i get sent back to my mainVC but i have the delete toggle on the left side of the cells and i have no way of removing it.

```
    #pragma mark Swipte cell to delete (see comment)
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    return YES;
}

// bug: when deleting from search controller and ending search, VC does not end editing.
// todo: move this into the updateVC and make it a button to work around bug above (or just fix the bug you noob..)
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete){
        Contacts * contacts = [[Contacts alloc] init];
        if (tableView == self.searchDisplayController.searchResultsTableView){
            contacts = [listOfFilteredContacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSString* URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"removed website for security reasons", contacts.pidJSON];
            NSDictionary * dictionary = [JSONHelper loadJSONDataFromURL:URL];
            [listOfFilteredContacts removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        }
        else{
            contacts = [listOfContacts objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            NSString* URL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"removed website for security reasons", contacts.pidJSON];
            NSDictionary * dictionary = [JSONHelper loadJSONDataFromURL:URL];
            [listOfContacts removeObjectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
        }
        [tableView reloadData];
    }
}
```

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with Xcode. Please read the tag's description.

Comment: Yea I fixed that after I posted. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you call

```
[tableView setEditing:NO];
```

when you press the cancel button?

I suppose that you call that function but with TRUE somewhen..

Regards.

Comment: Minor nitpick but use `NO` and `YES`, not `FALSE` and `TRUE` for `BOOL` values. It's a bit of a convention.